# Mono for Android LVL and

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-lvl

Has anyone created a C# implementation of the [Android LVL](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html) and the [Downloader Library](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html#AboutLibraries) yet? Or the [Play Expansion Library](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html)?

What I mean its either someone has the bindings done already or has someone has translated the libraries into its C#/.Net versions - translated them.

If not then I could start on it, as there has been some questions about this and I would like to use Google's new 4GB expansion of the APK size, as well as the LVL in my apps.

PS: I didn't quite know where to ask this. Maybe someone could point out a better place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEW**

I just want to point out the new bindings of the official Java library:

https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/GoogleAndroidVending

**OLD**

I started work on the C#.NET version of th LVL and Expansion Library:

https://github.com/mattleibow/Android.Play.ExpansionLibrary

any help will help all those who may want to use it in their apps